# XPath filter on the basis of ID value

Tags: xml, xpath, domxpath

From below XML I want to extract `Mobile_Number` values which is under `values/value` tag. How can I make this generic, because we can have multiple options later on instead of single `Mobile_Number` option.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request>
  <header>
    <businessTransactionID>ABCD</businessTransactionID>
    <externalCorrelationID>UABCD</externalCorrelationID>
    <sentTimestamp>2016-12-23T14:21:11.261+01:00</sentTimestamp>
    <sourceContext>
      <host>stackoverflow</host>
      <application>browser</application>
      <operation>ExtractXMLTAGVALUE</operation>
    </sourceContext>
  </header>
  <body>
    <serviceCharacteristic>
      <specification>
        <ID>Mobile_Number</ID>
      </specification>
      <values>
        <value>13008421</value>
      </values>
    </serviceCharacteristic>
  </body>
</Request>
```

I tried below XPath queries but in vain:

```
//*[local-name()='name'][text()='Mobile_Number']/../*[local-name()='value']/text()
```

Below query will work but then again it is not on the basis of ID value which is `Mobile_Number` -

```
string(/*/*/*[local-name()='serviceCharacteristic']/*/*[local-name()='value'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
//serviceCharacteristic[specification/ID='Mobile_Number']/values/value/text()
```